# Internet working really slow

Tags: networking, internet, steam, connection

I tried to check earlier questions but couldn't really find solution for this.

I do have 4G mobile connection which is connected to PC with USB. Ubuntu 18.10 does find it and all that, but speed is like max 200kbit/s, no matter from where I do download something (Steam, APT-GET, Firefox etc, everything is slow af).

Now every other computer does get 10mbit/s any time of the day with same connection so that led me to think that it must be something in Ubuntu whats wrong.

So any ideas?

(EDIT: Using Wifi gives me about 2.5mbit/s, so it's better than when using with cable, but it's still not anywhere near the speed I do get with Windows / Other machines)
(EDIT 2: Actually Wifi didnt help.. It works few first mins like it should, and then speed drops back to 100-200kbit/s.)

Answer (score 1):

As a test, try disabling IPv6 and see if that helps.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

As another test, try booting the Ubuntu machine with a live CD (or USB) to rule out that the problem could be the hardware. If it's fast, the problem is in the current Ubuntu configuration. If it's slow booting from Live media, then that points to the hardware.

Comment: Nope, didnt help at all. It made DL speeds just more worse, now getting only 30kbit/s anymore.

Comment: Re-enable ipv6 again by running the same commands again, but this time with =0 in each instead of =1

Comment: Yeah I did figure that out itself too, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Finally had time to test with Live USB, internet is slow with it too.

Comment: So that sort of points to the hardware but there's one other possibility: the NIC might need a driver that's not included in the Ubuntu distro. Or it's possibly just the hardware itself. Do you have another NIC you could use as a test? ...either with the Live USB or with the installed OS.